# Azure Blob Storage Cost Analysis

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Last month we got **5K** bill from Azure for my production workload, $1160 only for blob storage.

I have a single storage account for all my services (Function, WebJob etc.), Under storage account, I'm only using Blob and I didn't store any big file on that account.

I have many **Functions** and **Webjobs** processing data from **Eventhub** and storing checkpoint information into block blob. One of my function processing 15M request per-day and storing Checkpoint in the blob.

I re-visit [Microsoft documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) but unable to break this cost with my containers/Areas. Basically, I want to understand Storage, Ingress, Egress and Read/Write wise cost so I can take appropriate action.

[image]

Comment: See if this blog post helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is still not rectified, for more specialized assistance on this kindly contact Azure Billing and Subscription team would be the best to provide more insight and guidance on this scenario: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/, it's free, and it's the best choice for scenario.

Comment: You'll need to contact the Storage team. The Cost Management + Billing team cannot help here. Unfortunately, Storage doesn't share usage details at a container/blob level, which is what you need. Best workaround would be to get usage details from Azure Monitor and multiply that by the price to understand the specific cost per container/blob.